# Openlayers 3, jquery Ajax initialising in Jquery.success()

Tags: openlayers-2, events, ajax

I have this nice fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mindsupport/cujfjby4/14/

Openlayers 3 map initialized in ajax request and all data (points, line etc.) attached in jquery success() method, but map doesn't seen, it's is not initialized, but all objects a added to the global linkMap variable. Why? I've tried withoiut Ajax call, gust pure json data and it works...